# how do I perform the below python operation in pandas/ dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

below is my dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'Year': [2021, 2022, 2023, 2024, 2025],
                    'Tval' : [1, 9, 8, 1, 6]
})
```

I want to create a new column with output as shown in the snap attached.

in snap one multipliers (2.3,1.2,1.3,2.6 and 1.13) are randomly generated.
likewise for snap two and snap three.

whats the most efficient way to perform this operation as its a simplified version of the original problem (which has over 30k rows). Could use loop but its going to be very, very inefficient.

[image]

Comment: How are those values (referring to the last image, 2.13, 1.82, 1.3) coming? Do we have some logic or some fixed values?

Comment: no login, just assume they are randomly generated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the value of each row to be the product of subsequent rows with random values (random values recalculated for each operation).  You can do that as follows:

```
values = df.sort_index(ascending=False)['Tval']
values = values.expanding().apply(lambda x: np.sum(x*np.random.random(size=len(x))))
df["values"] = values
```

result:

```
   Year  Tval     values
0  2021     1  10.342499
1  2022     9  15.595990
2  2023     8  11.491088
3  2024     1   5.447966
4  2025     6   3.689064
```

Explanation:

- reverse the row order so `expanding` operates on all rows for first index, one row for last
- apply `expanding()` to sum rows of greater or equal index, randomly weighted.  Weights are recalculated each iteration.
- adds "values" to original dataframe (assignment/join is done on index value, no need to sort the series before adding to df)

As a sanity check, remove the random weighting and observe that this reduces to a reverse cumsum operation:

```
values = df.sort_index(ascending=False)['Tval']
values = values.expanding().apply(sum)
df["values"] = values
```

A similar solution can be used if the weights need not change between iterations.  As one of the other solutions suggest, you could also pre-calculate all the random weights and take an inner product. This will be memory inefficient but may be significantly faster, as `apply` is not vectorized.

Comment: very ingenious, liked it! and thanks for all the explanation that was really helpful

Comment: Same loved the answer. I was going more along the lines of cum-sum but I don't think that solution will be as elegant as the solution suggested by @anon01.

Answer (score 1):

The operation you're performing is a dot product, where you can account for the decremental use of data by setting weights to 0

```
weights = np.random.rand(5, 5)
weights = np.tril(weights)

print(weights)
[[0.80446016 0.         0.         0.         0.        ]
 [0.38560755 0.45014049 0.         0.         0.        ]
 [0.61068876 0.91918189 0.66418596 0.         0.        ]
 [0.78442001 0.63551564 0.35635216 0.14712083 0.        ]
 [0.54315584 0.20083916 0.28262627 0.01919842 0.58714358]]
```

The dot product will the first row of `weights`, multiply it by the values of `df["Tval"]`, then sum each of those products. Then it will take the 2nd row of `weights` and do the same thing, however since we set the first value in the 2nd row of weights to 0, we will essentially ignore the first value of `df["Tval"]` and multiply/sum the rest of the values. So on and so forth.

```
df["value"] = df["Tval"] @ weights
print(df)
   Year  Tval      value
0  2021     1  19.181775
1  2022     9  11.324420
2  2023     8   7.936429
3  2024     1   5.792162
4  2025     6   5.243747
```

Comment: actually, thats is a good answer as well. thanks. probably need to use weights = np.tril(weights) in your codes.

Comment: Very nice approach, I would be interested to see how performance compares with an `apply` solution.

Comment: whoops, sorry about that. swapped `triu` for `tril`. But yeah this won't be as memory efficient for a larger dataframe/number of weights. So I expect that for smaller datasets the that the dot product will outperform the `apply` approach. However I expect that the `apply` approach will outperform the dot product for very large datasets.